# Is it possible to replace PHP with NodeJS?

Tags: customization

I started working with **WordPress** recently, because I don't have much familiarity with the **PHP** language, I would like to know if there is any way to program with **NodeJS** in WordPress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

You can create your custom Node backend that communicates with WordPress via [REST](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) or [GraphQL](https://www.wpgraphql.com/), but if you want to use WordPress' functionality (such as `add_filter`, etc.), you need to use PHP.

See this as an opportunity to learn a new programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You are limited to what you can do with NodeJS using the REST API. As @kero explained you can't use functions like add_filter/add_action.